# Reporting services access issue from asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, asp.net-identity, sql-server-2016

We are connecting to SQL Server Reporting Server from an ASP.NET application using Reporting services.

We are facing intermittent issues when we try to connect to Report Server. (SQL Server 2016).  When checking the logs of Report Server, we noticed that sometimes application or app pool access  as user and sometimes as NT `Authority\Networkservices`.

The following code is used to pass credentials

```
ReportExecutionService rptExeSvc = new ReportExecutionService();
rptExeSvc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

In **web.config** we have

```
<value>http://servername/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx</value>
```

We cannot enable the service account because of security compliance issues. Could you please help me to resolve this

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

We migrated from SQL 2012 to 2016 and for compliance purpose are restricing use of service account and prefer machine account for server to server access.